# Initialize an array in class constructor

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

I can easily create an array like this:

```
int[] someArray = {1,2,3}
```

and that's nice. Now, lets say that I want to instantiate a new object of SomeClass and the constructor takes some arrays as parameters, how come I can't do the following?

```
SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass ({1,2,3},{'h','i'})
```

How can I initialize the array in the constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do

```
new SomeClass (new int[] {1,2,3}, new char[] {'h','i'})
```

Comment: Gah, of course! I had already tried doing it with int[] {1,2,3}.

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass (new int[] {1,2,3}, new char[] {'h','i'})
```

Comment: I think the letters were meant to be `char`

Answer (score 2):

The reason why is simply that there is special syntactic sugar to treat this:

```
int[] someArray = {1,2,3};
```

as meaning this:

```
int[] someArray = new int[] {1,2,3};
```

and no special syntactic sugar for other places where `new int[] {1,2,3}` might occur.